# How to include react library in react cli project

Tags: reactjs

I am using [react-super-select](https://github.com/alsoscotland/react-super-select) library

I create app using react cli provided by react. I have installed the library using npm install. HOwever when i include the library in my component i get error

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
>   or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You
>   likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in

I have included using the import statement below

```
import {ReactSuperSelect} from 'react-super-select/lib/react-super-select';
```

what error i am doing and how do i make the component work.

Comment: could you console.log ReactSuperSelect and see if its NOT undefined/null ?

Comment: Everything works fine. Only when i include this component i get this error in browser and CLI. Below is the console error.:
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.

Comment: try with this import.  import {ReactSuperSelect} from 'react-super-select'